# Mongo Aggregate Pipelines - Multiple Lookups in another Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some trouble understanding aggregate pipelines when doing a seemingly complex match up with another collection. The goal is to get a list of videos that a specific user has no `video_impression` entry in the analytics collection for.

My data looks something like this:

```
db={
  "videos": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "1's Video",
      "status": "complete",
      "privacy": "public"
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "name": "2's Video",
      "status": "complete",
      "privacy": "public"
    },
    {
      "_id": "3",
      "name": "3's Video",
      "status": "complete",
      "privacy": "public"
    },
    {
      "_id": "4",
      "name": "4's Video",
      "status": "complete",
      "privacy": "private"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5",
      "name": "5's Video",
      "status": "flagged",
      "privacy": "public"
    }
  ],
  "analytics": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "user": "1",
      "event": "video_impression",
      "data": {
        "video": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "user": "2",
      "event": "video_impression",
      "data": {
        "video": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have managed to get a matcher working but it works *"globally"* ie. it does not take in to consideration the user id so it's giving back documents that don't match anyone.

```
db.videos.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "status": "complete",
      "privacy": "public"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "analytics",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "data.video",
      as: "matched_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "matched_docs": {
        $eq: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I tried adding another `$lookup` stage to the pipeline to look up the `user` field but that didn't seem to work either as the data was always empty. [Here's a Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/adfjx4c-qNC) of the issue I'm having that may help explain it further.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want your documents to look like after the search is complete. I'm just having trouble understanding exactly what you need. You say "*The goal is to get a list of videos that a specific user has no video_impression entry in the analytics collection*" but all of your `analytics` documents have a `"event": "video_impression"`.

Comment: Good job on the sample documents, showing what you tried and the Mongo Playground link  Especially for someone new to SO. +1

Comment: @jQueeny Sorry about that! I should have provided a more complete example of the data, there are other events in there as well and the collection is quite large. My goal was an array of video ids that had no `video_impression` event record for a specific user ie. the specified user had not had any of the resulting videos impressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Firstly, this aggregation would be better to run from the `analytics` collection than the `videos` collection. Or even better, using the `users` collection if you have it.

**2.** As per [jQueeny's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557526/mongo-aggregate-pipelines-multiple-lookups-in-another-collection#comment136730586_77557526), the 'analytics' collection example is a bit incomplete. I'll assume each event only exists once so if a user watches two videos, there would be two entries in `analytics` rather than just one with an array of the videos. PS. I recommend that you change this so that it's an array of object id's in `data` per event-type, with separate records per user or even combining them all into one, depending on how you plan to use it later.

`anaylytics` collection:

```js
[
  { "_id": "1", "user": "1", "event": "video_impression", "data": { "video": "1" } },
  { "_id": "2", "user": "2", "event": "video_impression", "data": { "video": "2" } },
  { "_id": "3", "user": "2", "event": "video_impression", "data": { "video": "3" } },
  { "_id": "4", "user": "2", "event": "liked_video", "data": { "video": "2" } }
]
```

**3.** Strategy here is to use the [pipeline syntax of `$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection) to get all the video ids using an [**Uncorrelated** subquery](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-an-uncorrelated-subquery-with--lookup). It has the advantage of [only being run once and then using the cache](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-uncorrelated-subqueries-performance):

> *MongoDB only needs to run the `$lookup` subquery once before caching the query because there is no relationship between the source and foreign collections. The `$lookup` subquery is not based on any value in the source collection. This behavior improves performance for subsequent executions of this query.*

However, if the collection of videos is too big and the per-stage document becomes >100 MB, this pipeline will fail and you'll need to use a correlated subquery.

**4.** The method used here is:

a) Using the `analytics` collection, filter to only `video_impressions` events, group by `user_id` and then create a `set` (unique array) of the videos they've watched/have an impression.

b) Use a lookup to get **all** the video ids for "public+complete" vids into one array

c) do a difference between the all videos and videos with impressions.

**5.** Btw, if you want to do this for only one user at a time, like for a web page/FE, then add `user: <user_id>` in the first match stage with `event`.

```js
db.analytics.aggregate([
  {
    // select only the video_impression events
    $match: { event: "video_impression" }
  },
  {
    // first uniquify your users but you should
    // probably run this from the users collection
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      impressioned_vids: { "$addToSet": "$data.video" },
      // remove this if you want the user as _id
      user: { "$first": "$user" }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } },
  {
    // uncorrelated subquery which should only run once
    // and then is cached
    $lookup: {
      from: "videos",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            status: "complete",
            privacy: "public"
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            video_ids: { $push: "$_id" }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "all_vids"
    }
  },
  {
    // put it conveniently into a single list
    $set: { all_vids: { $first: "$all_vids.video_ids" } }
  },
  {
    // these are the public-complete videos which that user has not seen
    $set: {
      unimpressed: {
        $setDifference: [ "$all_vids", "$impressioned_vids" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of the other fields, uncomment to debug
    $project: {
      user: 1,
      unimpressed: 1
    }
  }
])
```

With my modified `analytics` collection and your original `videos` collection, this is the result:

```js
[
  {
    "unimpressed": ["1"],
    "user": "2"
  },
  {
    "unimpressed": ["2", "3"],
    "user": "1"
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YeeEmwpkvnI)

---

**Option 2**

If the list of `all_vids` is too big for the *uncorrelated `$lookup`*, then it will need to be a **correlated $lookup**, which executes once per document. The main change is in the `$lookup` stage, where I check that the video is not in the list of impression/watched videos (or in this case, intersection is empty). This requires assigning the "seen videos" array to a variable in `let` and then using that in the lookup-pipeline.

```js
  {
    // correlated subquery which executes per record
    $lookup: {
      from: "videos",
      let: { seen_vid_ids: "$impressioned_vids" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            status: "complete",
            privacy: "public",
            $expr: {
              $not: {
                $in: ["$_id", "$$seen_vid_ids"],
              },
            },
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "unseen_vids"
    }
  },
  {
    // these are the public-complete videos which that user has not seen
    $set: {
      unimpressed: "$unseen_vids._id"
    }
  },
```

[Mongo Playground with the full aggregation](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kb-b67zkzHE)

Comment: Thank you so much for the super detailed answer, this pointed me in the right direction and I was able to solve the problem with Option 2.